# Loop to move/resize images on all slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to create a PowerPoint with 200-300 slides with a picture and the person's name on each slide. I turned to PowerPoint and VBA to get the job done. I've got the name issue handled. I've got the importing of images working with the Photo Album. It places the images large and in the center. I turned to using a Macro (see below) to move/resize the image. It only works for one slide. I've searched all over on how to loop so that it will do this for all slides but I can't figure it out. I'm new to VBA so I don't know where to begin. Thank you in advance for any advice or help!

```
Sub ResizeImages()
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 300
    .Left = 45
    .Top = 45
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Sub resizeImage()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            With shp
                .Height = 400
                .Width = 300
                .Left = 45
                .Top = 45
            End With

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Because OP mentioned names, we might assume that there are other shapes on the slide, so it'd be best to add  IF SHP.TYPE = MSO PICTURE THEN and then add END IF after END WITH.  That way you'll only resize/reposition the picture, not other shapes on the slide.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code so you don't have to pull your hair out if your a noob like me

```
Sub pictureformatloop()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
    With shp
        .Height = 300.3
        .Width = 639.7
        .Left = 1125.7
        .Top = 270.4
    End With
End If
Next
    Next
```

End Sub